# When can I sign up for the introductory rate at the careers site?

Tags: support, jobs

When can I sign up for the introductory rate at the careers site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All* rates are introductory rates ($29 for 3 years) until November 9th, so .. well, anytime now. :)

**Note that you must fill out at least 50% of your CV to get the filing option.**

Comment: When was answered with 'anywhere'. Awesome.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the tip, I had not yet filled in at least 50% of my CV yet and was searching for the sign-up option.